# Prevent UITableView from scrolling when new cells are inserted

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I've seen this question being asked several times and, despite having implemented each proposed solution by the community, I still haven't succeeded. What I'm implementing is a basic public chat app. I need to display many messages that I receive through my API inside a UITableView. In order to have a chat feeling, I've turned both my UITableView and UITableViewCell upside down by changing their *transform* property to `CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)`. Instead, to add cells to the UITableView, I first add the incoming message to the array via `messages.insert(message, at: indexPath.row)`and then I call `insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: animation)` (where *indexPath* is created this way `IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)`). When I'm at the bottom of the UITableView everything works great: the new cells appear from bottom to top accompanied by a smooth animation. The problems start when I scroll to top by a few pixels. Take a look at these images to better understand the difference.

[image][image]

What I would like to achieve is preventing the UITableView from scrolling unless I'm at its very bottom so that, if the user scrolls to top with the aim of reading a past message, he can do so without any trouble caused by the movement of the UITableView.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction. Thanks

Edit: I'm using automatic UITableViewCell height if that helps.

Edit: here's my current code:

I'm using a generic wrapper `class ListView<Cell: UITableViewCell, Item>` with this method used for adding new items:

```
func add(_ item: Item) {
    items.insert(item, at: 0)

    if contentOffset.y > -contentInset.top {
        insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .top)
    } else {
        reloadData()
    }
}
```

I had to use `-contentInset.top` to check if I'm at the very bottom of the scroll view since I've previously set the contentInset to `UIEdgeInsets(top: composeMessageView.frame.height - 4, left: 0, bottom: 4, right: 0)` for layout reasons. Again, I've set *estimatedRowHeight* to 44 and *rowHeight* to UITableViewAutomaticDimension.

Comment: Have you tried saving the content offset of tableview before inserting new row and reapply it after insertion?

Comment: Sure. It didn’t work. Perhaps has something to do with the fact everything is upside down?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
func add(_ item: Item) {
    // Calculate your `contentOffset` before adding new row
    let additionalHeight = tableView.contentSize.height - tableView.frame.size.height
    let yOffset = tableView.contentOffset.y

    // Update your contentInset to start tableView from bottom of page
    updateTableContentInset()

    items.append(item)       

    // Create indexPath and add new row at the end
    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: objects.count - 1, section: 0)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)

    // Scroll to new added row if you are viewing latest messages otherwise stay at where you are
    if yOffset >= additionalHeight {
        tableView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath, at: .top, animated: true)
    }
}
```

Here is the method to update `contentInset`. It will give you the same effect which you were achieving by this `CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)`

```
func updateTableContentInset() {
    var contentInsetTop = tableView.frame.size.height - tableView.contentSize.height
    if contentInsetTop <= 0 {
        contentInsetTop = 0
    }
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: contentInsetTop, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
}
```

Comment: The idea of distinguishing the two cases is good but it's not working. I've changed it to: `if contentOffset.y > -contentInset.top {
            reloadData()
        } else {
            insertRows(at: [indexPath], with: animation)
        }` The `CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)` is a little trick to turn the UITableView upside down

Comment: This looks fine. But I think when you transform your view with `CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: -1)` then your `tableView` can not update it's `contentOffset` correctly which cause this problem. I have updated my answer. Please have a look at that. I hope it will solve your problem.

Comment: I've tried your code and… it works! I'll never change the transform property again :D Thank you thank you thank you

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem too — glitchy shifting of the content offset when inserting or deleting the first row (my table view is not inverted but has a big static table header component).

I resolved it finally by having an extra empty cell for the first row (height set to 1), and now when I delete or insert the *second* row, there's no glitch anymore, the offset stays as expected.

(iOS 16.5 and Xcode 14.2)